# How to escape a ' within a string?

Tags: python, sql

I have a little script that creates a certain INSERT SQL statement for me.

For postgresql I need to wrap the values to be inserted within two single quotes.

Unfortunately some of the value strings to be inserted also contain a single quote, and I need to escape them automatically.

```
for line in f:
    out.write('(\'' + line[:2] + '\', \'' + line[3:-1] + '\'),\n')
```

How can I make sure that any single quote (e.g. ' ) inside `line[3:-1]` is automatically escaped?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

e.g. the line

```
CI|Cote D'ivoire
```

fails due '

**Update 2:**

I can't use double quotes in values, e.g.

`INSERT INTO "App_country" (country_code, country_name) VALUES ("AF", "Afghanistan")`

I get the error message: `ERROR: column "AF" does not exist`

This however works fine:

`INSERT INTO "App_country" (country_code, country_name) VALUES ('AF', 'Afghanistan')`

Comment: You might just want to use the DBAPI methods instead, which already escape unsafe characters.

Comment: On re-reading your question I am not sure I got the question right. Could you provide the contents of `line`?

Comment: @Keith any pointer how I do that with DBAPI?

Comment: So this: `('CI', 'Cote D'ivoir'),` would not work with SQL because of the single quote after the "D"?

Comment: exactly. I have updated the question again, to make this case clear. Its tricky, don't know what to do.

Comment: @Kave So this is really an SQL problem in a way. What would be an acceptable string for this particular example: `('CI', 'Cote D\'ivoir')` or `('CI', 'Cote D\\'ivoir')` .. what would be palatable for the SQL query string?

Comment: @Levon you just *have* to *have* the objects in Python objects before hand - that's all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [PEP-249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), the DBPI is a generic interface to various databases. Different implementations exist for different databases. For postgres there is [psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/). from the docs:

```
cur.execute(
...     """INSERT INTO some_table (an_int, a_date, a_string)
...         VALUES (%s, %s, %s);""",
...     (10, datetime.date(2005, 11, 18), "O'Reilly"))
```

You simple pass your parameters in a tuple. The underlying library escapes it for you.  This is much safer and easier than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard way to escape a quote is to double it:

```
'This won''t be a problem.'
```

So replace every quote with two quotes (and use double quotes in Python to stay sane):

```
out.write("('" + line[:2] + "', '" + line[3:-1].replace("'", "''") + "'),\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Never use a generated, rolled-your-own escaping for DML. Use the appropriate DBAPI as Keith has mentioned. Work would have gone into that to make sure escapes from various sources and type conversion can occur almost transparently. If you're using DDL such as a `CREATE TABLE whatever (...)` - you can be more slight slack-handed if you trust your own datasource.

**using data shown in example**:

```python
import sqlite3

text = "CI|Cote D'ivoire" # had to been escaped as it's a string literal, but from another data source - possibly not...

code, name = text.split('|', 1)

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.execute('create table something(code, name)')
db.execute('insert into something(code, name) values(?, ?)', (code, name))

for row in db.execute('select * from something'):
    print row
# (u'CI', u"Cote D'ivoire")
```

Comment: +1 from me. Gave me some ideas thanks. I found Keith's solution easier as I had already psycopg2.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete solution toadd escape characters to a string, use:

```
re.escape(string)
>>> re.escape('\ a.*$')
'\\\\\\ a\\.\\*\\$'
```

for more, see: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: It's not a regular expression s/he's trying to escape.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there are some SQL related limitations, but you could always use double quotes to surround your string that contains the single quote.

Eg.

```
print "That's all Folks!"
```

or single quotes to surround double quotes:

```
print 'The name of the file is "rosebud".'
```

Comment: OP, Keep in mind backslash interpolation happens in all but raw strings in Python!

Comment: Unfortunately there is a limitation: `INSERT INTO "App_country" (country_code, country_name) VALUES 
("AF", "Afghanistan")`  gives the error `ERROR: column "AF" does not exist`  PostgreSQL doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: -1 The OP is inserting variable text *data* into a column in an SQL database. Formation rules for Python string constants are quite irrelevant.